# How to get the count from Publishing Queue

Tags: 2013-sp1

We have implemented Web Deployer in our `Tridion 2013 SP1` Environment. Could you please help me to get the count of item(s) from Publishing Queue based on state selection.

Answer (score 7):

It is difficult to tell from your question exactly what you are trying to achieve.

If you are trying to get the count of items with a particular state from within the Publishing Queue, then you can do this by setting your filtering options within the `Filter Publishing Tasks` dropdowns and then clicking on one of the 'funnel' icons alongside the header that you want to know the count for:

[image]

This will give you the total count (i.e. `All`), along with the sub-totals for each option.

Alternatively, you could do this using a [Core Service](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90) client or using a [GUI extension](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D). However, both of these would require custom code.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. You got me correctly and from your answer I got my required information. Thank you once again.

Comment: In that case, please accept Jonathan's answer to indicate that it solved your issue. This will help other people, that have the same question, know what worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a Core Service app that polls the Publish Queue and gets items based on a certain state. Please have a look at the [Blog Article](http://www.curlette.com/?p=1349)  and the [Core Service Code](https://github.com/rcurlette/TridionPubQMonitor/blob/master/TridionPubQMonitoringService/TridionPubQService.cs).

Beware - The 'Show Tasks' button on the Publish Queue screen and also the code above to get the list of items in the Publish Queue is very DB intensive. This is something you do not want to do every second for example. Using it normally is OK, but it is not something you want to do a hundred times in a minute...

An alternative to the Publish Queue Windows Service polling would be to tap into the `Event System` and listen for finished publish transactions...